# Data Tables are not loading when i redirect my page using self.do_action in odoo(openERP7) qweb screen

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, openerp-7, qweb

When i redirect my page using `self.do_action` in `odoo(openERP7)` it is not loading Data Tables in the new page.
In other pages it was working fine. But in a particular page if i redirect using this `self.do_action` is not working. But `self.act_window` is working fine in the same page.

If any one faced this same issue please let me know.

Update:I found a similarity of problems in my code. I have a model like performance.review and some other models also. All the `self.do_action` used in this model is not loading Data tables properly. But other model screens does perfectly.
Is there any relation between model extension and using `self.do_action`?
Here is my code,

```
module.ReviewForm= instance.web.Widget.extend({
    events: {
        'click #review_tree_view':'load_tree_view',
    },

load_tree_view: function (event) {
        var self = this;
        self.do_action({
            type: 'ir.actions.client',
            tag: "performance.review",
            name:'Tree view',
            target: 'current',
        });
    },
```

Comment: Code Updated @JainikPatel

Comment: you can this line replace 'click #review_tree_view': self.load_tree_view,

Comment: @JainikPatel When i replaced that line like you mentioned above, i got this javascript error `TypeError: fn is undefined`

Comment: your function is with argument so you can pass your argument in this function self.load_tree_view(event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a small mistake done by myself. Im using the same model for many qweb screens, and each time Im rendering form view using `self.do_action` I did't emptying the existing tree view.

It can be easily done by adding this line.
Now data tables loading properly and perfectly.

```
load_tree_view: function (event) {
    var self = this;

    self.$el.empty();

    self.do_action({
        type: 'ir.actions.client',
        tag: "performance.review",
        name:'Tree view',
        target: 'current',
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript file, you could add an event to a buttons class name like this:

```js
bind_events: function () {            
        this.$('.oe_btn_class_name').on('click', this.on_call_new_view_function);
    },
```

Then the "on_call_new_view_function" is called when a click event occurs and opens the new view like this:

```js
on_call_new_view_function: function () {
        var self = this;
        // you can pass in other data using the context dictionary variable
        var context = {
            'id': this.id,
        };
        // the action dictionary variable sends data in the "self.do_action" method
        var action = {
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                res_model: 'model.name',
                view_id: 'view_id',
                view_mode: 'form',
                view_type: 'form',
                views: [[false, 'form']],
                target: 'new',
                context: context,
        };
        // self.do_action accepts the action parameter and opens the new view
        self.do_action(action);
    },
```

Comment: `type: 'ir.actions.act_window'` is used for openERP screen only right?.But mine is a qweb screen know? How it will work. Explain me if Im wrong

Comment: When you click on a button available in the pop-up window, you need to return {'type': ir.actions.act_window'} and  Openerp use a qweb templating.

Comment: I have following doubts,
               In the above action dictionary, `model.name` will be common for all qweb pages I have in that model `performance.review`. And there is no specific format for form view and tree view in qweb screen, Where can i specify my screen in that code?

Comment: OMG! @patel, When I use this code it doest load my qweb screen. It simply loading all the columns in that model with openERP screen? I think because of there is no specification about name of that qweb screen.

Comment: your view is define in view_type and view_mode and also set your res_model = 'performance.review' and you can create a form view or tree view for this model in qweb. this view display when you click on button.

Comment: Already Im having more than 5 qweb screens for this model 'performance.review'. Where should i specify that this is the screen name  to be loaded in your code when the button is clicked?

Comment: if you have a multiple qweb screen the you can define  'view_id':view_id, .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92033/discussion-between-jainik-patel-and-vanjith).